# How can you group symlinks with directories in `ls` output but tell the difference?

Tags: directory, ls, symlink

In `ls` output, I'd like to group symlinks that point to directories along with the rest of the directories, but still have a way of telling that it's a symlink either with color or an appended symbol.  Is there a way to do this?

If a symlink points to a directory, you can tell in output from `ls` by using the `-F, --classify` argument and by setting `LINK target` in the `dircolors`.  Then it will be shown as `dir_link@`, but with the same color as a directory.

The `ls` command can group directories together with the `--group-directories-first` option.

The only way I can see to group symlinks to directories along with other directories is to use the `-L, --dereference` option.  But this changes both the appended indicator as well as the color of the entry (even if you set links to be displayed as their own color independent of the target); it's then indistinguishable from a regular directory.

I'm using GNU `ls` on Linux.

Comment: Doesn't the ls colors entry allow you to color it differently?

Comment: This isn't exactly what you are looking for, but I use `ls -al` (often aliased as `ll`) and when it displays symlinks, it lists them like `directoryname -> path/to/linked/location`. it usually colors valid links one color, and broken links in red.

Comment: @FrankThomas I'm hoping for something that will work with any output option, not just the long listing.  But if you add the `--dereference` option in order to get the directory links sorted next to the directories, then it even stops showing the target information in the long output!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, as of [GNU coreutils v8.31](https://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=9394) in 2019,

> ls --group-directories-first will also group symlinks to directories.

(Copied from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/704864/528311)

Answer (score 1):

The LS_COLORS variable has an option for symbolic links. The LN option, if given a unique color compared to the DI option, will show all symbolic links as that color instead.

See http://linux-sxs.org/housekeeping/lscolors.html for basic options. There is ways of setting individual extension types to their own colors, so there may be a way to set symbolic link directories a different color than symbolic link files, but that takes playing around.

Comment: The problem is that to get the link sorted with the directories, you (I think) have to use the `--dereference` option, which then makes the entry use the DI option instead of the LN option in LS_COLORS.

Comment: @ohspite you tested it? Drat.