# Is there a simple way to group soft links to directories with directories when using --group-directories-first?

Tags: ls

I like the `--group-directories-first` flag for `ls`. My .zshrc has this line in it:

`alias ls="ls -h --color='auto' --group-directories-first"`

The only thing I don't like is that symbolic links to directories don't get grouped with the directories.

Are there any switches I can add to the `ls` command that will cause symbolic-links-to-directories to group with directories? I'm disinclined to build a compound command, because I like being able to add additional switches to `ls` on the fly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you group symlinks with directories in \`ls\` output but tell the difference?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232394/how-can-you-group-symlinks-with-directories-in-ls-output-but-tell-the-differen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, as of [GNU coreutils v8.31](https://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=9394) in 2019,

> ls --group-directories-first will also group symlinks to directories.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use the `-L` flag:

> -L, --dereference
>
> when showing file information for a symbolic link, show information for the file the link references rather than for the link itself

For example, assume I have the files and directories below:

```
$ ls -l --group-directories-first
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 2 user group 6 Nov 30 08:19 zdir1
drwxr-xr-x. 2 user group 6 Nov 30 08:19 zdir2
-rw-r--r--. 1 user group 0 Nov 30 08:20 file1
-rw-r--r--. 1 user group 0 Nov 30 08:20 file2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 user group 5 Nov 30 08:23 symlink -> zdir2
```

The symlink gets sorted with the directories when `-L` is used:

```
$ ls -lL --group-directories-first
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 2 user group 6 Nov 30 08:19 symlink
drwxr-xr-x. 2 user group 6 Nov 30 08:19 zdir1
drwxr-xr-x. 2 user group 6 Nov 30 08:19 zdir2
-rw-r--r--. 1 user group 0 Nov 30 08:20 file1
-rw-r--r--. 1 user group 0 Nov 30 08:20 file2
```

---

As you noticed, `ls` no longer indicates whether the files are symlinks are not. I'm not familiar with a way in `ls` to show a symlink once it's been dereferenced, but I wrote a hacky bash function to do it for you:

```
lsd() {
        ls -lL --group-directories-first | while read line; do
                file=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $NF}')
                ls -ld "$file" 2>/dev/null | grep -q "^l"
                if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                        symlink=$(ls -l $file | awk '{print $(NF-2),$(NF-1),$NF}')
                        echo "$line" | sed -e "s/^./l/" -e "s/$file/$symlink/"
                else
                        echo "$line"
                fi
        done
}
```

Essentially, the script will determine if the file output from `ls -lL --group-directories-first` is a symlink or not. If it is, the first character is changed to an `l`, and what the symlink points to is appended to the end of the line.

```
$ lsd
total 0
lrwxr-xr-x. 2 user group 6 Nov 30 13:49 symlink -> zdir2
drwxr-xr-x. 2 user group 6 Nov 30 13:49 zdir1
drwxr-xr-x. 2 user group 6 Nov 30 13:49 zdir2
-rw-r--r--. 1 user group 0 Nov 30 13:49 file1
-rw-r--r--. 1 user group 0 Nov 30 13:49 file2
```

Comment: What if the symbolic link is pointing to file? OP only wants links pointing to directories.

Comment: @Debian_yadav: The `-L` flag will dereference the symlink and see that it points to a file, and won't place it with the directories at the top.

Comment: That's pretty close to great.  Do you know if there's a way to get it to keep the symlink -> target notation as well?

Comment: Related question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232394/how-can-you-group-symlinks-with-directories-in-ls-output-but-tell-the-differen?rq=1

Comment: @JoshuaD: See my latest edit.